# Get individuals percentages and calculate the average of them in dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

`I need to calculate a percentage for each months for A measure based on total B measure. I mean A/B per month. Then, I need to calculate the average between months (divided by quarters), example:

| Month | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 1 | 3 |
| Feb | 1 | 1 |
| Mar | 2 | 2 |

So,
`for Jan -> 1/3 = 33,3%`
`for Feb -> 1/1 = 100%`
`for Mar -> 2/2 = 100%`

the average between months by quarter should be:
`(33,3 + 100 + 100) / 3 = 77,7%`

But power bi calculates it as:
`Sum of A = 4`
`Sum of B = 6`
the average between months by quarter: 66,6%

how can I get 77,7% on power bi?

Tried calculating individuals percentage, but out of hand... I have many years and 12 months each.`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a varTable using a variable, this will allow you to have your total.
For

```
Mesure =
VAR _VarTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( 'MyTable', 'MyTable'[Month] ),
        "avgAB", DIVIDE ( [Measure A], [Measure B] )
    )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX ( _VarTable, [avgAB] )
```

The way the overall average is calculated seems ambiguous at best